# Using koin in Multi-module application

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, multi-module, koin

Hi in a multi modules app, I am loading child modules using loadKoinModules() and unloading it using unloadKoinModules() in feature module my code looks like

```
class FeatureActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
    private val loadFeatures by lazy { loadKoinModules(featureModule) }
    private fun injectFeatures() = loadFeatures

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        injectFeatures()
    }

   override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unloadKoinModules(featureModule)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but problem start when another instance on same activity is loaded. While current activity is in background. App crash due to error below

```
org.koin.error.BeanOverrideException:  Try to override definition with Factory
```

Is there a way to avoid this error

Comment: I'm trying to build a modular application in which feature module contain an activity. That activity can again load itself as a new instance. In this case we get org.koin.error.BeanOverrideException:  Try to override definition with Factory.

Answer (score 6):

It is somehow correct what you are doing, you can unload dynamically as you do this is why `unloadKoinModules` has been added [link](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/419)

but why aren't you unloading `onStop`? according to android lifecycle and what you want to do, you have to `unload` in `onStop`

When activity gets focus `onCreate` will occur (and you will load modules), later when activity loses focus, `onStop` will occurs (and you will unload modules) and the circle between the events...

[image]

```
class FeatureActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
    private val loadFeatures by lazy { loadKoinModules(featureModule) }
    private fun injectFeatures() = loadFeatures

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        injectFeatures()
    }

   override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unloadKoinModules(featureModule)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution I am looking for. Consider the twitter profile page as a feature module Activity, you can navigate from one profile page to another. This means you need to create another instance of that activity. Now in this case how to load and unload modules.

Comment: but your issue is your workflow, currently you are trying to load/unload in incorrect lifecycle states. You could also define featureModule to override every time it gets created, or don't unload the module, the concept to unload is for reloading, but in your situation doesn't look like that you want that

Answer (score 3):

Koin won't let to you redefine an already existing definition *(type,name,path …​)*. You will run into an error.

You need to [allow definition override](https://github.com/ibrahimAlii/koin/blob/03081e4533eb1fbca18eb9648f831ea660610302/koin-projects/koin-core/src/docs/asciidoc/modules.adoc#overriding-a-definition-or-a-module) :-

```
val featureModule = module {

    // override for this definition
    single<yourType>(override=true) { YourClass() }
}
```

ALSO you can override on module level instead of overriding on definition level only:-

```
val featureModule = module(override=true) {

    single<yourType> { YourClass() }
}
```

**Important**:-
Order matters when listing modules and overriding definitions. You must have your overriding definitions in last of your module list.

Comment: There is downside with this approach refer to https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/419#issuecomment-487968325

Comment: @Deepanshutyagi You can go with reload approach `unload` and `reload`, but It doesn't matter to much since it's doesn't happen to much in application.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Load your feature module in the top-level application level and don't scope it to any activity lifecycle.
- Add a reference-counting wrapper around your module load/unload so the module is not reloaded if it is already loaded, and it is only unloaded when the usage count is zero. (You can simplify this by not caring about unloading and change the count to just a "initialised" boolean.)

Comment: Ya but this looks  like a fix not a good solution to the problem. Currently I am using mixed form of approach mentioned in first and second  point. But need a better approach